# Cascading DropDown not return value

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a two cascading dropdown, when I run the application everything works fine, because the cascade works, but when I get the value of the dropdown only get the value of first dropdown. The second I always get the value of zero.

The ViewModel code:

```
public class MyViewModel
    {
        public string SelectedUniversidadId { get; set; }
        public string SelectedCiudadId { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<UNIVERSIDAD> Universidades { get; set; }
    }
```

Partial view code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
         $('#universidad').change(function () {
             var selectedUniversidadId = $(this).val();
             $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetCiudadList", "Consultorio", new { Area = "Superusuario", controller = "Consultorio" })', { UniversidadId: selectedUniversidadId }, function (myData) {
                 var citiesSelect = $('#ciudad');
                 citiesSelect.empty();
                 $.each(myData, function (index, itemData) {
                     citiesSelect.append($('<option/>', {
                         value: itemData.Value,
                         text: itemData.Text
                     }));
                 });
             });
         });

     });
</script>
   @model RolesMVC3.Areas.Superusuario.Models.MyViewModel
   <div>
    Universidad: 
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedUniversidadId, new SelectList(ViewBag.IdUniversidad, "IdUniversidad", "Nombre"), "-- Selecione Universidad --", new { id = "universidad" })
</div>
<div>
    Ciudad: 
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedCiudadId, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "-- Seleccione Ciudad --", new { id = "ciudad" })
</div>
```

Controller code:

```
 public ActionResult GetCiudadList(int UniversidadId)
        {
            decimal idd = (decimal)UniversidadId;


            var universidades = (from u in db.UNIVERSIDAD
                              join s in db.SEDE_UNIVERSIDAD on u.IdUniversidad equals s.IdUniversidad
                              join c in db.CIUDAD on s.IdCiudadSede equals c.IdCiudad
                              where u.IdUniversidad == idd
                              select c).ToList();
            var myData = universidades.Select(a => new
            {
                Text = a.NombreCiudad,
                Value = a.IdCiudad.ToString(),
            });
            return Json(myData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Thanks and blessings

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 0):

You need a controller action that receives 2 parameters (selected values for the 2 dropdowns). Also, pay attention to the values of the name attributes for the input elements. the name of the parameters need to be the same as the "name" input attribute.